# Grid appears in ggplot2 depending on axis option

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I have created a map that shows that shows the intensity of a variable by making a grid of the entire United states. That works pretty well but the problem that a grid appears when I save the plot. The following simplified code reproduces my problem.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)

#Construct grid
n.dots <- 1000

x <- seq(0, 100, length.out = n.dots)
y <- seq(0, 100, length.out = n.dots)

grid <- expand.grid(x, y)
colnames(grid) <- c("x", "y")

grid$value <- grid$x*grid$y


#Make graph
mytheme <-  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
  axis.title = element_blank(),
  plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines"),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  plot.title = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.grid = element_blank(),
  legend.title=element_blank(), 
  legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"), text=element_text(size=10), 
  legend.position="none")

p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=grid, aes(x=x, y=y, colour = value), size = 0.1) + scale_colour_gradient("value", low="green", high = "red") + theme_bw() + mytheme 

ggsave(p, filename = "Map intensity.png",  width = 4, height = 4, units = "in", dpi = 600)
```

[image]

The png file shows a grid which I do not want. By commenting out axis.text and axis.title in theme options I selected the problem disappears.

```
#Make graph
mytheme <-  theme(#axis.text = element_blank(),
  #axis.title = element_blank(),
  plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines"),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  plot.title = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.grid = element_blank(),
  legend.title=element_blank(), 
  legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"), text=element_text(size=10), 
  legend.position="none")


p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=grid, aes(x=x, y=y, colour = value), size = 0.1) + scale_colour_gradient("value", low="green", high = "red") + theme_bw() + mytheme 


ggsave(p, filename = "Map intensity_2.png",  width = 4, height = 4, units = "in", dpi = 600)
```

[image]

In that last png file the graph is all smooth as I want it and there is no grid. But it contains axis text and axis titles, which I do not want. What is causing this behavior?

One solution could be to increase the point size but I am hoping to keep the graph as precise as possible. I am interested in knowing why the axis options change the appearance of a grid in the file that is saved.

Thank you.

Comment: I can reproduce that. I think the device fails somehow at higher dpi values. Remove `dpi=600` and the grid will disappear.